# Leaflet.js dynamic multiple maps on same page

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

I'm creating a web app where a user can upload their own maps and then they are displayed with Leaflet.js within Bootstrap nav tabs. This is within a Python Flask app.

I have got it to work, although only one maps settings for bounds, etc. are used. So say if I had a Westeros and Middle Earth map, the bounds calculated for the Middle Earth map would also be used for the Westeros map.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    {% for map_file in map_list %}
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            var h = img.height;
            var w = img.width;

            var map = L.map('{{ map_file[1] }}', {
                minZoom: 1,
                maxZoom: 5,
                center: [0,0],
                zoom:1,
                crs: L.CRS.Simple,
            });

            var southWest = map.unproject([0,h], map.getMaxZoom() -1);
            var northEast = map.unproject([w,0], map.getMaxZoom() -1);
            var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
            {% set map_img_dir = '/static/users/'+user+'/maps/'+map_file[0] %}
            var image = L.imageOverlay('{{ map_img_dir }}', bounds).addTo(map);
            map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
        }
        {% set map_img = 'users/'+user+'/maps/'+map_file[0] %}
        img.src = "{{ url_for('static', filename=map_img) }}"
    {% endfor %}
});
```

(small note for context, map_list is a 2D list of files with and without their extensions, e.g. `['middle_earth.jpg','middle_earth']`)

I have attributed this problem to `map`. I understand that with multiple maps I have seen use different map variables for the each map, however since the maps are being created dynamically and I am unsure of how many maps there will be, I am unsure of how I would be able to implement this.

I appreciate any help/advice.

**EDIT:** I solved it by using `{{ map_file[1] }}` as a variable name instead of `img`, so the variable names will be something like `middle_earth` or `westeros`. *Another problem is that the zooms are not animated when I use the scroll wheel, it is very blocky and goes quite fast?*

Comment: Might rather be an issue with `img` variable being reused within same scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `{{ map_file[1] }}` instead of the name `img`. Additionally, I added this, [shown here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224932/problem-with-map-tiles-loading-with-leaflet-and-bootstrap):

```
{% set map_tab_id = map_file[1]+'-tab-id' %}
$("a[href='#{{ map_tab_id }}']").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    map.invalidateSize();
});
```

After `map.setMaxBounds(bounds);` which solved the blocky/non animated zoom.

For completeness, this is the map tab panes which are within a jinja for loop:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="{{ map_tab_id }}" >
    <div id="{{ map_file[1] }}" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
</div>
```

Where `map_tab_id` is just `map_file[1]` (e.g. westeros or middle_earth) with '-tab-id' on the end.